# How to get and set Core Data Entity's properties using an array?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a CoreData entity , (myEntity) which has assume 10 properties. Is there a way to get the 10 properties in an array and set the property values using said array?

For example:

```
//To get the property:

NSArray *arrayOfProperties = <Some command>;

...

//and then to set the property value,instead of:
myEntity.property1 = <value>;
//set the property like so:
[[arrayOfProperties objectAtIndex:1] <some command to set the value>];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following:

```
// Create the entity in the managed object context:
    MyEntity *myEntity = (MyEntity *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

// Set the properties of the entity:
    entity.property1 = arrayOfProperties[0];
    entity.property2 = arrayOfProperties[1];
    entity.property3 = arrayOfProperties[2];
    // etc...
```